# Using the phrase "from X to X" versus using "between Xs"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage

I want to say that physicians differ on the diagnosis of an illness for patient Joe. What is the difference between:

- *The diagnosis differs between physicians*
- *The diagnosis differs from physician to physician*

Is the latter more informal (or simply incorrect)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are valid sentences, and both mean essentially the same thing. Often in cases like this there are subtle differences in connotations -- one might be more emphatic, or carry some other implication -- but I'm hard pressed to think of any difference in meaning here.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with Jay that there is little difference between those sentences. IMO, both express a simple idea rather awkwardly by making *diagnosis* the grammatical subject.

One could restate the sentence: "Physicians do not concur on the diagnosis of Joe's illness."  That formulation makes clear that *medical opinion* is involved.

Answer (score 1):

Both are interchangeable. However, if I was to be really specific, the second sentence implies that every physician has a different diagnoses where the former sentence may imply that the physicians are split between two different diagnosis.

Despite that, no-one will ever be that picky when reading those sentences, so you don't have to worry about it. Both are perfect for any situation.